# SML How to check variable type?

Tags: sml

Is there any way to check/test the type of a variable?

I want to use it like this:

```
if x = int then foo
else if x = real then bar
else if x = string then ...
     else .....
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ML languages are statically typed, so it's not possible for something to have different types at different times. `x` can't sometimes have type `int` and at other times have the type `string`. If you need behavior like this, the normal way to go about it is to wrap the value in a container that encodes type information, like:

```
datatype wrapper = Int of int | Real of real | String of string
```

Then you can pattern-match on the constructor:

```
case x of Int x    -> foo
        | Real x   -> bar
        | String x -> ...
```

In this case, `x` is clearly typed as a `wrapper`, so that will work.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to do what you want in general, even if `x` is of polymorphic type (without doing the wrapping yourself as Chuck suggests).

This is a deliberate design decision; it makes it possible to make very strong conclusions about functions, just based on their types, that you couldn't make otherwise. For instance, it lets you say that a function with type `'a -> 'a` must be the identity function (or a function that always throws an exception, or a function that never returns). If you could inspect what `'a` was at runtime, you could write a sneaky program like

```
fun sneaky (x : 'a) : 'a = if x = int then infinite_loop() else x
```

that would violate the rule. (This is a pretty trivial example, but there are lots of less-trivial things you can do by knowing your type system has this property.)