# Check if parameter is a list

Tags: sml, smlnj

Is it possible in SML to write a general purpose function that returns true iff the parameter x is a list?

```
fun isList(x) = .......
```

Expected Usage:

```
- isList(4);   (* returns false *)
- isList([1, 2, 3]); (* returns true *)
```

Comment: What would the type of such a function be?

Comment: Return type of the function should be boolean

Comment: Maybe this question will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713948/sml-how-to-check-variable-type

Comment: But the *input type* is part of a function type as well -- and you seem to be asking for a function which lacks any well-defined input type.

Comment: @John Coleman Well, I understood the point, but how can I determine if an expression evaluates to a list or an atom, somehow?

Comment: If by "expression" you mean "string" then it becomes a well-defined parsing question. The answer would be to write an SML parser and associated type inference algorithm. Needless to say, that is a lot of work. Perhaps SMLNJ makes some of its compiler internals accessible in a usable way.

Comment: On the other hand if by "expression" you don't mean "string" but instead something which can have both 4 and [4] as instances, no such notion of expression exists in SML.

Comment: @JohnColeman "...no such notion of expression exists in SML" This answer satisfies me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible in that you can try to pattern match and then handle the appropriate exceptions. But either way that defeats the point of functional programming. In functional programming the goal is to build useful functions with the types abstracted away. Any type specific function calls should be abstracted away as inputs.

Take `map: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list` for example. The whole goal is to have abstracted the manipulation you wish to preform away to a function that is passed in (in curried form).

So casing on input types misses the point. So if you wish to do different things based on the input types, you should pass that operation in as a function input.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible in SML to write a general purpose function that returns true iff the parameter x is a list?

No.

```
- fun foo 4 = false
    | foo [] = true;
! Toplevel input:
!     | foo [] = true
!            ^
! Type clash: pattern of type
!   'a list
! cannot have type
!   int
```